# TabBarView or IndexedStack for BottomNavigationBar - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

What is the best way to do the bottom navigation bar in flutter?

According to [Getting to the Bottom of Navigation in Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter/getting-to-the-bottom-of-navigation-in-flutter-b3e440b9386) the flutter team used `IndexedStack` with `Offstage` to show the widget when the user changes the tab, but I see there's another way of doing this by `TabBarView` to change between widgets with simple slide animation and also keeping each widget's scroll state

So what's the difference between the `IndexedStack` + `Offstage` and `TabBarView`? and what is the best way to change the current tab should I use something like `flutter_bloc` or just use `setState()`?

Answer (score 12):

### OverView

Well, there are many ways to implement `BottomNavigationBar` in Flutter.
But Using the `IndexedStack` method would create all the screens of the`BottomNavigationBar` at the starting. This can be fixed using `TabBarView`.

Here's how I Implemented `BottomNavigationBar` in my app using `CupertinoTabBar` and `PageView` as it would make only one screen at the starting. And also using `AutomaticKeepAliveMixin` as it wouldn't let the screens to be recreated again.

---

### KeyPoints

- `PageView` with `PageController` by which you can easily shift between screens.
- `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` doesn't let the screens to be recreated and thus there is no need to use `IndexedStack`.
- Use `Provider` and `Consumer` to recreate only the `CupertinoTabBar` when changing the `currentIndex`. Instead of using `setState()`, as it would recreate the whole screen letting all the widgets to get rebuild. But here were are using `Provider` to recreate only `TabBar`.

---

### Code Example

> HomePage (`BottomNavigtionBar`)

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
 _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
PageController _pageController;

@override
void initState() {
  _pageController = PageController();
  super.initState();
}

@override
void dispose() {
  _pageController.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return  Scaffold(
    // Wrapping the CupertinoTabBar in Consumer so that It only get 
    // recreated.
    bottomNavigationBar: Consumer<HomeVM>(
      builder: (context, model, child) {
        return CupertinoTabBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white10,
            currentIndex:  model.currentPage,
            onTap: (index) {
                index == model.currentPage
                ? print('same screen')
                : _pageController.jumpToPage(
                    index,
                  );
                 model.changePage(index);
                }, 
            items: bottomNavItems);
      },
    ),
    body:ChangeNotifierProvider(
           create: (_) => locator<HelpVM>(),
           child: SafeArea(
                    top: false,
                    child: PageView(
                    controller: _pageController,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    children: <Widget>[
                          FrontScreen(),
                          WorkRootScreen(),
                          HelpScreen(),
                          AccountScreen(),
                     ],
                   ),
          ),
       ),
  );
 }

  const List<BottomNavigationBarItem> bottomNavItems = 
   <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
     BottomNavigationBarItem(
       icon: const Icon(
       FontAwesomeIcons.home,
     ),
   ),
    //...... bottomNavigationBarItems 
  ];

}
```

> HomeVM (Using `Provider` to change the index and recreate only `TabBar` using `Consumer`)

```
class HomeVM extends ChangeNotifier {
 int _currentPage = 0;

 int get currentPage => _currentPage;

 void changePage(int index) {
   this._currentPage = index;
   notifyListeners();
 }
}
```

> FrontScreen (Here we are using `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` to retain the state by not recreating the Widget)

```
   class FrontScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
      _FrontScreenState createState() => _FrontScreenState();
    }
    
    class _FrontScreenState extends State<FrontScreen>
        with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      // VIMP to Add this Line.
        super.build(context);
        return SafeArea(
         // Your Screen Code   
        );
      }
    
      @override
      bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
   }
```